# Notifications not showing Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to bring up a notification after set period of time using:

```
scheduleNotification(getNotification("Notification content..") differ);
```

and the following functions -

```
private Notification getNotification(String content) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification");
        builder.setContentText(content);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);

        return builder.build();
}


private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, long delay) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);        
        long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}
```

After logging the delay value, I get 57580 which is roughly 57 seconds, but even after this period of time, I do not get any notification on status-bar.

Please help.

Comment: you should do the trick with a BroadcastReceiver. Shedule the alarm and start Notification in onReceive().....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `BroadcastReceiver` to get notifications from the system.

```
public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        getNotification(String content);
    }        
}
```

And remember to declare the class in your AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
```